# May the fourth be with flu

Tags: code-golf, grid

Since tomorrow is the 4th of May, here's a little Star Wars themed post to prepare you mentally to all the bad jokes coming tomorrow.

**BACKSTORY**

During a session of the galactic senate all the senators are sitting in an `n*n` grid.
A sudden outbreak of JarJar flu (which lasts forever and causes the infected to speak like JarJar Binks) causes some of the senators to get infected.

Here's an example with a `6*6` grid where the `X` are the infected senators, the corresponding list is : `[[0,5],[1,4],[2,3],[2,1],[3,3],[3,0],[4,5],[0,5]]`:

[image]

After that the infection begins to spread step by step. Two senators are **adjacent** if they share a whole edge on the grid (i.e., top,bottom,right,left), which means we exclude diagonals.

We can conclude a senator can be adjacent to 2,3 or 4 other senators and claim the following rules for the infection :

- A senator that has been infected stays infected forever
- A senator is infected at a step if he was adjacent to 2 or more infected senator at the previous step

Here's an example with the previous grid which shows the 2 first steps of the infection :

[image]

After the nexts steps all the senate will be infected

**YOUR TASK**

Your code doesn't need to handle invalid inputs like a list greater than `n*n` or coordinates that aren't distincts.

Your code will take as input a list of couples of integers (or a binary grid or any other format that suits your language) and an integer `n` (which can be unnecessary if you use another format than a list) , for instance :

```
8 [[1,2],[1,1],[7,4],[2,7],[4,3]]
```

n being the side of the grid which means the grid will be a n*n grid, and the list of couples of integers being the coordinates of the cells of the initally infected senators.

The bottom left of the grid is [0,0] and the top right is [n-1,n-1]. The top left is [0,n-1].

Your code must output an integer :

`-1` or a falsy value or an error if the whole grid will never be totally infected
or the minimum number of steps required to infect the whole grid

**Test cases**

```
6 [[0,5],[1,4],[2,3],[2,1],[3,3],[3,0],[4,5],[5,0]] => 7

4 [[1,1][0,3][1,0][3,0][3,3]] => 9
```

Remember that this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), thus the shortest answer in bytes wins !

Comment: [Related post on Mathematica.SE.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/140099/2305)

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/38446/be-an-epidemiologist)

Comment: What's the minimum value of `n`? Is there a max value?

Comment: @mbomb007 there's no max value in theory but it should be computable. For the minimum value I'd say 1 which outputs 0 or -1

Comment: Looks like a job for Mathematica's `CellularAutomaton`...

Comment: @mbomb007 See the post I linked in the first comment. `ListConvolve` is probably shorter.

Comment: @Antoine Can we use 1-based indexing for number of generations, i.e. 1=senate is already fully infected, 2=fully infected one step later, 3=... And then 0=infection never takes over? Is this ok?

Comment: @Adám Well I don't know if it's fair for those who are using the 0-indexing but personally I don't mind

Comment: Minecraft reference: a water will be a full block of water if there are two adjacent full blocks (provided that the well is 1 block deep).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## MATL, <s>29</s> 28 bytes

```
tn:"tlY6Z+1>Z|t?@.]]Nl=?l_]&
```

Input is in the form of a 2D matrix of 1's and 0's

Try it at [**MATL Online**](https://matl.io/?code=tn%3A%22tlY6Z%2B1%3EZ%7Ct%3F%40.%5D%5DNl%3D%3Fl_%5D%26&inputs=%5B1+0+0+0+1+0%3B+0+1+0+0+0+0%3B+0+0+1+1+0+0%3B0+0+0+0+0+0%3B0+0+1+0+0+0%3B0+0+0+1+0+1%5D%0A&version=19.10.0)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab user input as a 2D matrix
t       % Duplicate the inputs
n:      % Count the number of elements in the input (N) and create the array [1...N]
"       % Loop this many times (maximum number of steps we analyze)
  t     % Duplicate the top element
  lY6   % Push the 2D array => [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]
  Z+    % Perform 2D convolution (and maintain the size)
  l>    % Find all values that are >= 2
  Z|    % Perform an element-wise OR with the previous state
  t?    % If all elements are 1's
    @.  % Push the current index and break out of the loop
  ]     % End of if 
]       % End of for loop
Nl=?    % If there is only one element on the stack
  l_    % Push a negative one
]       % End of if statement
&       % Display the top stack element
```

Comment: @LuisMendo Unfortunately I don't think so because there are some 0's in the output of the convolution which would become -1 and therefore be "true"

Comment: How about `tn:"tlY6Z+1>Z|t?x@D.]]N?xl_`? (I'm haven't tested much). If all elements are 1 at some point, display the loop index immediately and delete stack. At the end of the loop, if the stack is non-empty delete and push `-1`

Answer (score 3):

## APL (Dyalog 16.0), 54 characters or 60 bytes

Takes enclosed matrix as argument, returns the step number which completes infection, i.e. 1=is already fully infected. 0=does not fully spread, which is just 1 + the OP's numbers.

54 characters (Unicode):

```
(≢×0=0∊⊃){(⊢≡f←⊢∨2≤{+/,⍵×3 3⍴0 1}⌺3 3)⊃⍵:⍵⋄(⊂f⊃⍵),⍵}⍣≡
```

60 bytes (Classic):

```
(≢×0=0∊⊃){(⊢≡f←⊢∨2≤{+/,⍵×3 3⍴0 1}⎕U233A 3 3)⊃⍵:⍵⋄(⊂f⊃⍵),⍵}⍣≡
```

`⌺` is equivalent to `⎕U233A`

Examples' run:

```
      g←(≢×0=0∊⊃){(⊢≡f←⊢∨2≤{+/,⍵×3 3⍴0 1}⌺3 3)⊃⍵:⍵ ⋄ (⊂f⊃⍵),⍵}⍣≡
      ⎕IO←0
      b←⊂⊖⍉~@(⎕JSON'[[0,5],[1,4],[2,3],[2,1],[3,3],[3,0],[4,5],[5,0]]')⊢0⍴⍨2⍴6
      g b
8
      b←⊂⊖⍉~@(⎕JSON'[[1,1],[0,3],[1,0],[3,0],[3,3]]')⊢0⍴⍨2⍴4
      g b
10
```

The steps are as follows:

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┬─────────────┐
│ X       X   │ X X     X   │ X X X   X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X X │
│   X         │ X X X       │ X X X X     │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │
│     X X     │   X X X     │ X X X X     │ X X X X     │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │
│             │     X       │   X X X     │ X X X X X   │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │
│     X       │     X X     │     X X X   │   X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │
│       X   X │     X X X X │     X X X X │     X X X X │   X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │ X X X X X X │
└─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┴─────────────┘
┌─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┐
│ X     X │ X     X │ X     X │ X     X │ X     X │ X     X │ X   X X │ X X X X │ X X X X │ X X X X │
│         │         │         │         │       X │     X X │   X X X │ X X X X │ X X X X │ X X X X │
│   X     │   X     │   X X   │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │ X X X X │ X X X X │
│   X   X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │   X X X │ X X X X │
└─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┘
```

Answer (score 2):

## Python, 231 bytes

```python
g=input()
q=lambda r,c:g[r][c]if(0<=r<m)*(0<=c<m)else 0
m=len(g);p=t=0;n=range(m)
while not all([r for k in g for r in k]):h=[[g[r][c]or sum([q(r+1,c),q(r-1,c),q(r,c+1),q(r,c-1)])>1 for c in n] for r in n];t+=1;0/(g!=h);g=h
print t
```

It raises an error if it isn't possible.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bY1BbsMgEEX3PsV0BzJRYRs6uQhiQQjBKHjiEKIc37VjO5XaSiP9p6evP2PERMOjMt7cMLv@eHJQhN9HU6zxNp2hfPXg6ATlgHJOv@XkQ74HkE2PORCLXA9YUWrC4igG1vPm2aUcgK4VXM7MFDhfC1wgEcQXlhkvlu87NGb9Oen7o2fmxkqrhOdigt0GwrdqhZ3ilh/Ua8fPO2R/Nsnq2qLS8pPFD@y4jtg1Q0lUoY6jMUqA3G5mK8xK71vUYtUv9X9L/m0tVln7DQ)

Comment: `0/0` saves two bytes from `raise`. Maybe `1/(g!=h)` would work? (then the whole `while` could be inlined too).

Comment: @JonathanAllan I updated it, thanks for the input.

Comment: `q=lambda r,c:g[r][c]if(0<=r<m)*(0<=c<m)else 0` saves 12. You can remove the space between (a) `1` and `for` and (b) `]` and `for` too.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Updated again. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 49 bytes

```
J^UE2*lK.uS{+NeMf>hT1r8S@Jsmm+VdkNs_MB_MBU2Q)qJeK
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=J%5EUE2%2alK.uS%7B%2BNeMf%3EhT1r8S%40Jsmm%2BVdkNs_MB_MBU2Q%29qJeK&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%5B1%2C2%5D%2C%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B7%2C4%5D%2C%5B2%2C7%5D%2C%5B4%2C3%5D%5D%0A8%0A%5B%5B0%2C5%5D%2C%5B1%2C4%5D%2C%5B2%2C3%5D%2C%5B2%2C1%5D%2C%5B3%2C3%5D%2C%5B3%2C0%5D%2C%5B4%2C5%5D%2C%5B5%2C0%5D%5D%0A6%0A%5B%5B1%2C1%5D%2C%5B0%2C3%5D%2C%5B1%2C0%5D%2C%5B3%2C0%5D%2C%5B3%2C3%5D%5D%0A4&debug=0&input_size=2).

Uses 1-indexing for the output.

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 132 bytes

```
f=s=>(w=s.search`\n`,t=` `.repeat(w+1),t+=s+t,t=s.replace(/0/g,(_,i)=>1-t[i]-t[i+=w]-t[i+=2]-t[i+w]>>>31),t==s?0/!/0/.test(s):1+f(t))
```

Where `\n` represents the literal newline character. Takes input as a string of `0`s and `1`s in a newline-delimited array. Returns `NaN` if the grid will never become fully infected.